# uploading image files and keeping track with mysql table

Tags: mysql, innodb

What happens to a locked-row in InnoDB tables, that is called to UPDATE by another user ?
Does it wait until it's unlocked and then UPDATED by the other user call ? And consequently, the user page will wait until un-locked, and then executed, consisting in a delay in the other user display page ?

I have a website where people can upload pictures, and a table with only 1 row, which holds the current number of pictures uploaded (and a folder name "1", "2" etc), where one folder can hold a certain number of pictures (say 7000) ...that's why they increment.

I'm curious if I did my script right.

There is basically 1 row in a table (mya_pictures), where there's a column for the current folder used ("1", "2", "3"...) and the current number of pictures in the current folder (which cannot surpass 7000 - max number of files in that folder)....

Incrementing of files is done with UPDATE, once the files have succesfully uploaded.
I'm wondering if in multi-user environment this will work good.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs :

If a second transaction wants to update a row or lock a table already locked by a prior transaction in an incompatible mode, InnoDB adds a lock request for the row to the corresponding queue. For a lock to be acquired by a transaction, all incompatible lock requests previously entered into the lock queue for that row or table must be removed (the transactions holding or requesting those locks either commit or rollback).

You can read here about Innodb locking:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

~K